# How to access all cardviews in a recyclerview, on item click of a particular cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, nestedrecyclerview

I have a main recyclerview,which displays my main cardview. Now this main cardview got a child recyclerview inside,which holds the child cardview.
Now when i click on the anyof the main cardview,the child recyclerview with child cardviews become visible.
If i click that main cardview again,then the child recyclerview becomes invisible.

Now what's happening is, if i click a main carview,then its child recyclerview will be come visible.
Now if i click another main cardview,then its child recyclerview will appear. like this

[image]

What i want is,if i click another main cardview,then,if any other childviews are visible , then it should become invibsle. In another words,the child rewcyclerview of the main cardview which i click should only be open. All others child recyclerviews should be invisible/ close.

Now what i want is a way to access all the main carviews in the main recyclerview,when i click a particular main cardview,so that i cam make the child recyclerview of all those main cardviews invisible.

Hope i made my point clear.

I want only one childview open at a time like this..

[image]

This is the onBindViewHolder of main Recyclerview holder adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MainHolder holder, final int position) {

    MSeasonTanks mSeasonTanks=mSTankList.get(position);
    MoultingDataEntry moultingDataEntry=moultList.get(position);
    holder.textViewOne.setText("Tank Number : "+mSeasonTanks.getTName());

    ChildRVAdapter childRVAdapter=new ChildRVAdapter(moultingDataEntry,mSeasonTanks.getTID(),holder);

    holder.childRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    holder.imageViewDirection.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand);

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(holder.childRecyclerView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                holder.childRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.imageViewDirection.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand);
            }else{
                holder.childRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageViewDirection.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_collapse);
            }
        }
    });
    holder.childRecyclerView.setAdapter(childRVAdapter);
}
```

So on the main carview onClick method to access all the main cardviews,so that i can get their child recyclerviews invisible if its open.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How Do I Use setOnFocusChangeListener with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242007/how-do-i-use-setonfocuschangelistener-with-recyclerview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will Suggest is.

-> Suppose you have data for the main Recyclerview like
MainRecyclerItemData, It should have one boolean flag, isExpanded

-> isExpanded = true (Inner Recyclerview is Visible)

-> isExpanded = false (Inner Recyclerview  is hidden)

-> Now When User click on main recycler item, Pass MainRecyclerItemData's id for the clicked item to your activity via interface to method suppose (OuterItemClicked(String id)).

-> Now loop the wholelist, and for the wholelist make isExpanded = false except for the item with the clcked id (for it make it true).

-> Now call adapter.notifydatasetchanged()

```
 //In onBindViewHolder() you should have code to handle isExpanded flag, 
if(isExpanded){
// Show inner recyclerview
}else{
// Hide inner recyclerview
}
```