# How to trigger other CardView element in recyclerview than clicked?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a method in adapter using recyclerview I basically display some elements of `cardViews`.

How to trigger method on other element where usually I use

```
cardView.setOnClickListener {
// MY action on specific} cardView element
```

for example when I click third element, `<MY ACTION>` happens in second element?
Inside cardView I can i.e use:

```
statusButtons.toggleVisibility(!statusButtons.isVisible)
```

but it will only work when I trigger actual element using method

```
cardView.setOnClickListener { }
```

I have found something similiar
[How to access all cardviews in a recyclerview, on item click of a particular cardview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210762/how-to-access-all-cardviews-in-a-recyclerview-on-item-click-of-a-particular-car)

but it is not directly related to my case, I need to make action on specific ID like

```
statusButtons.toggleVisibility(!statusButtons.isVisible) where I not have argument to change
```

Comment: Can you share your Adapter code also? Do you have an interface or lambda to send the click event back to Activity/Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(position)` function to get the `ViewHolder` at given position and call functions on that ViewHolder from the activity/fragment.
The function returns `null` if no `ViewHolder` exists at given `position`

```kotlin
class YourAdapter(
    onCardClick: (Int) -> Unit
) {

    ...

    inner class YourViewHolder {
        fun bind() {
            cardView.setOnClickListener {
                onCardClick(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
      
        fun operateOnCard() {
            statusButtons.toggleVisibility(!statusButtons.isVisible)
        }
    }
}

class YourActivity {
    
    ...

    val adapter = YourAdapter { position ->
        val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(position - 1) // Or whatever position you want
        (viewHolder as? YourViewHolder)?.operateOnCard()
    }
}
```

**Edit:** If you need `item.id` in the activity for choosing the ViewHolder, you can pass the item as well from the lambda.

```kotlin
class YourAdapter(
    onCardClick: (Int, YourItem) -> Unit
) {
  ...
  onCardClick(adapterPosition, item)
  ...
}
class YourActivity {
    ...
    val adapter = YourAdapter { position, item ->
        // Here you have access to item as well
    }
```

You can update the `onCardClick` lambda depending upon whatever info you need to send from adapter to activity. Also, if you want to send the id to the `operateOnCard` function, you can also do that.

Comment: Sounds nice also the solution was to use flow to observe all elements.

Comment: If I would like to use your solution how to get access to item.id from Activity?

Comment: I have updated the answer. See if this helps.

Comment: If this doesn't help, I would ask you to update the question and include details about  your current adapter setup, and what do `item.id` and `id` represent? How do you compute which card should handle the click when user clicks on a particular card?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
in Adapter

```
// define flowState
(...)
 val _stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(-1)
 val stateFlow = _stateFlow.asStateFlow()

// after every change of element
(...)
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    stateFlow.collect { id ->
                        statusButtons.toggleVisibility(item.id == id)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Although this may seem to have solved your problem, it is usually not recommended to create our own `CoroutineScope`. In your case, you are never cancelling the `CoroutineScope`s that you are creating. And it seems like you are creating one whenever a ViewHolder is bound to RecyclerView. This will lead to a large number of scopes and jobs which are running simultaneously which may cause various memory leaks.

Comment: How could I create only one job related to viewholder, recyclerview and only work in that scope then dissapear?

Comment: I see there is something like https://github.com/satoshun/CoroutineAutoDispose I could use it as well..
But I would like to do it without external libraries. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72232759/how-to-change-main-scope-to-another-in-recyclerview-adapter

Comment: `How could I create only one job related to viewholder, recyclerview and only work in that scope then dissapear?` It's actually not recommended to use `Flow`s and `CoroutineScope`s inside an adapter.