# How to change main scope to another in recyclerview, adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, kotlin-coroutines

This is my code in `adapter` using `recyclerView`. How to improve this code to not use Main Scope, but to use scope that could be disposal?
I need to have access to get the `item.id`, that's why I use it in adapter not in viewmodel/fragment.

```
 _stateFlow.value = item.id
```

my code in adapter

```
// define flowState
(...)
 val _stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(-1)
 val stateFlow = _stateFlow.asStateFlow()

// after every change of element
(...)
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    stateFlow.collect { id ->
                        statusButtons.toggleVisibility(item.id == id)
                    }
                }
```

EDIT1 answer for comment:
Without coroutine I can't use collect on stateFlow always when my id is changed.
My action is like I need to trigger element previously clicked when I click next one.

[image: without coroutine I an't use collect]

Comment: i highly doubt you need coroutines in your adapter in the first place, you should try to remove them entirely

Comment: answered in topic

Comment: why can't you make use of callbacks to move this away from your actual adapter ?

Comment: I think I've got your point I  could just make callback and set method in adapter fun myMethod() {
statusButtons.toggleVisibility(item.id == id)} and use it from fragment? I;m not sure how to make it. :)

Comment: But if you have any additional comments with this I would be thankful I tried to do it but maybe tommorow try again.
Greetings

Comment: Eventually can we make another jobscope in adapter and just make it like this? Thanks